# Define a custom paper size as default for all users for Samsung printer

Tags: windows, windows-registry, printing, printer, regedit

I want to define a custom paper size configuration for all users in several computers.

When I try to do this with any predefined paper size (A4, A5, Letter, etc.), it works correctly, but it doesn't work if it is a custom size.

I tried exporting the regedit keys in `HKCU\Printers`, but it is not working.

Printer model is Samsung M262x 282x.

OS is Windows 7 and the custom size I want to configure is Statement (It doesn't exist in this printer)

Comment: Where exactly are you configuring these defaults?

Comment: control panel -> view devices and printers -> rightclick over printer -> printer properties -> Advanced -> printing Defaults

Comment: Well it should stick, hmmmm, are you logged into an admin user account when making the changes?

Comment: Yes, I am. I tried with a local admin account and with a domain admin account. I noticed that this only happens with custom types. With the same procedure I can configure other paper sizes like A5.

Comment: Certain programs like word documents can override default settings, but I don't think this is your issue?

Comment: See if this way solves it>>>>>https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-7/q-how-do-i-create-custom-paper-size-printing-windows-7

Comment: It doesn't look like an application problem... I can configure one account to use this configuration, It just doesn't appear in other accounts.

Comment: My link shows a different way to create a custom paper size in print Server Properties then apply that form in printer properties., maybe it will work.

Comment: I was able to create the paper size in the "Print server properties" window, but it doesn't appear in the "printing preferences" list.

Comment: Bang head here>>>>>>X